# SQL Script Vertica how to calculate duration from specific date incremented by 30

Tags: sql, database, vertica

I have two tables.

T1 => has the start date of when a customer joined
for example customer id = 'id-123456' has joined in Feb 5th, 2020

T2 = is the second table where I have his activities and purchase date

I would like to use Vertica SQL for the monthly repeated orders or purchases as the following

```
Month-Year   Total_Acquired_Customer    Month1 Activity  Month2 Activity   Month3 Activity   Month4 Activity
jan2020      1000                       800              600               500               400
feb2020      3000                       1800             1200              900               700
```

each interval has to be more than 30 days. for example the customer joining day + 30 should give me M1 and the same increment for Month2, 3, 4

Comment: Can you add just a few rows with cust_id,purch_date, amount for T2, to let us understand the logic? `Month1 Activity` and `Month2 Activity` are not self-explanatory, at least for me

Answer (score 0):

Below is not a smart statement, but is it what you expect?

```
=> SELECT * FROM t1;
 customer_id |   joined
-------------+------------
 id-123456   | 2020-02-05
 id-789012   | 2020-01-12

=> SELECT * FROM t2 ORDER BY customer_id, purchased;
 customer_id | purchased  | activity
-------------+------------+----------
 id-123456   | 2020-02-10 |      100
 id-123456   | 2020-02-15 |      100
 id-123456   | 2020-03-10 |      200
 id-123456   | 2020-03-15 |      200
 id-123456   | 2020-04-10 |      300
 id-123456   | 2020-04-15 |      300
 id-123456   | 2020-05-10 |      400
 id-123456   | 2020-05-15 |      400
 id-789012   | 2020-01-15 |      100
 id-789012   | 2020-01-20 |      100
 id-789012   | 2020-02-20 |      200
 id-789012   | 2020-02-25 |      200
 id-789012   | 2020-03-20 |      300
 id-789012   | 2020-03-25 |      300
 id-789012   | 2020-04-20 |      400
 id-789012   | 2020-04-25 |      400

=> SELECT
->   to_char(t1.joined,'monYYYY') AS 'Month-Year',
->   SUM(CASE WHEN t2.purchased BETWEEN t1.joined AND t1.joined + INTERVAL '30 days' THEN t2.activity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Month1 Activity',
->   SUM(CASE WHEN t2.purchased BETWEEN t1.joined + INTERVAL '31 days' AND t1.joined + INTERVAL '60 days' THEN t2.activity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Month2 Activity',
->   SUM(CASE WHEN t2.purchased BETWEEN t1.joined + INTERVAL '61 days' AND t1.joined + INTERVAL '90 days' THEN t2.activity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Month3 Activity',
->   SUM(CASE WHEN t2.purchased BETWEEN t1.joined + INTERVAL '91 days' AND t1.joined + INTERVAL '120 days' THEN t2.activity ELSE 0 END) AS 'Month4 Activity'
-> FROM t1
-> JOIN t2 ON t1.customer_id = t2.customer_id
-> GROUP BY t1.joined
-> ORDER BY t1.joined;
 Month-Year | Month1 Activity | Month2 Activity | Month3 Activity | Month4 Activity
------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------
 jan2020    |             200 |             400 |             600 |             800
 feb2020    |             200 |             400 |             600 |             800
```